# Wyswig CSS Editors

Tags: javascript, css, wysiwyg

I'm in the middle of making a CMS and I am trying to find a WSYIWING like editors for CSS. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7975/1090389

Comment: Only slightly related. That conversation is about all WYSIWYG editors, where this one is specifically one that works in a browser (and can be implemented in a CMS).

Comment: Do you mean a tool that you can mess with the CSS of a site and see how those changes you've made affect how it looks?  Chrome's DOM inspector is pretty legit, Opera's as well. Firefox's built-in one is okay, but then the Firebug extension picks up the slack.

Comment: Yes, see how the changes look but for something a non-technical user can use. Chrome's DOM is great but I wouldn't ask someone who isn't a developer to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used [StyleMaster](https://westciv.com/style_master/). You should also take a look at [Espresso](https://espressoapp.com/).

But in fact what I use nowadays is [COMPASS](http://compass-style.org/) which is not a GUI tool but a very smart CSS framework.

Answer (score 0):

I believe he means a Javascript editor (would have posted as comment, can't do so yet)
http://jsfiddle.net/

Edit: If it is CSS, FF11 allows you to change the styles via Inspect Element -> Styles

Comment: Yes exactly, something like this but that is downloadable and installable.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://www.dockphp.com..
It is still in development but does a pretty good job..

Answer (score 0):

Rapid CSS is one the best. You can try it
http://www.rapidcsseditor.com/